# Webpack ERROR in missing path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I am getting an error whenever I try to run Webpack. It just says ERROR in missing path. The error goes away when I remove the module key in the configuration below:

```
module.exports = {                                                              
 entry: './client/scripts/app.js',                                           
 output: {                                                                   
     path: './docs/scripts/',                                                
     filename: 'bundle.js'                                                   
 },                                                                          
 module: {                                                                   
     loaders: [{                              
         test: /\.js$/,                                                      
         loader: 'ng-annotate!',                                             
         exclude: /node_modules|docs\/bower_components/                    
     }],                                                                     
 }                                                                           
};
```

Here is the error output:

```
Hash: 396f0bfb9d565b6f60f0
Version: webpack 1.13.1
Time: 76ms
    + 1 hidden modules

ERROR in missing path
```

My webpack config sits in the root of my project. The folder structure is below:

```
client
    scripts
        app.js    
node_modules
docs
    scripts
        bundle.js
    bower_components        
webpack.config.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mistake in `RegExp`, add `\` before `/`

```
/node_modules|docs\/bower_components/  
                  ^^
```

also after `ng-annotate` you don't need add `!`, because you are using only one loader

```
loader: 'ng-annotate'
                    ^^
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you.